# use NamedQuery or Criteria API

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

I have a complex query e.g. search employees with name, age, address, etc
I would like to append a `WHERE` clause if a parameter `IS NOT NULL`.

for example (pseudo code):

```
if (age != null) // then append age to the where clause
    whereClause += whereClause + AND age = :age"
```

I would like to use a `NamedQuery` in an `XML` file, but a `NamedQuery` does not support conditional where like myBatis

Can anyone help me resolve this problem?

Comment: The answer is in the title of your question: use the criteria API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this simple case/condition you can solve the problem with a NamedQuery:

```
SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE (:age IS NULL) OR (:age IS NOT NULL and e.age=:age)
```

If you want more complex queries (e.g. where you sort dynamically by the column), I would use Criteria API.